# Chatear con el cliente con la informacion obtenida de un array

Tags: html, jquery, sql, html5, mysqli

Tengo un codigo jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#myTable').dblclick(function(e){

var a=$('td:eq(0)', $(e.target).parents('tr')).text()
a = a.trim()
$("#id_buy").text(a)

var a=$('td:eq(1)', $(e.target).parents('tr')).text()
a = a.trim()
$("#name").text(a)

var a=$('td:eq(2)', $(e.target).parents('tr')).text()
a = a.trim()
$("#chattlf").val(a)

if(a!=""){
$("#md4").modal("show")

}

})
</script>
```

y mi consulta a la base de datos

```
<?
$sql="SELECT id_buy, name, tlf, from buys;
        if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {    
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  if($rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result)){

       
        /* Desplegamos cada uno de los registros dentro de una tabla */  
        echo "<div><table class=''id=myTable>";
        
        echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
             
                 echo"<th data-placeholder='Buscar ID Pago'> ID Pago </th>";
                 echo"<th data-placeholder='Buscar Cliente'> Cliente </th>";
                 echo"<th data-placeholder='Buscar tlf'> Tlf</th>";

              echo"</tr>";
              
              echo"</thead>";
              
        echo "<tbody>";
        /*Y ahora todos los registros */
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        
        $tlf_chat=trim($row['tlf']);
        $tlf1chat=str_replace("+","https://wa.me/",$tlf_chat);
       $tlf2chat=str_replace(" ","",$tlf1chat);

        echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td> $row[id_buy] </td>";
                echo"<td> $row[name]</td>";
                echo"<td> $tlf2chat</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        }
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Hasta aqui, todo va bien.

El problema es cuando intento usar el siguiente boton

```
<div class="modal" id="md4"">
  <a  target='_blank' id='chattlf' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'><i class='fab fa-whatsapp'> 
  </i> Chat with <b id='name'></b></a>";
</div>
```

Ccuando yo hago doble clic en una compra de mi tabla, aparezca el modal donde coloco datos de las compras y del cliente con . Y tambien añadi un boton que deberia redirigirme a chatear con el cliente a través de whatsapp. Pero no funciona. He aqui el problema. He intentando muchas cosas pero aun no he logrado nada.

Soy aprendiz, agradezco cualquier aporte